# How to make use of Case-Insensitive Contains in ArrayList

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code in ASP.Net C#

```
ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
            myArrayList.Add("Apple");
            myArrayList.Add("Banana");

            if (myArrayList.Contains("apple"))  // This returns false because Contains doesn't support a case-sensitive search
                statusLabel.Text = "ArrayList contains apple";
```

I get false , Since Apple not equals apple. I have even tried like

```
myArrayList.Contains("apple", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

But intellisense shows error. Is this really possible on ArrayList ?apple

Comment: ArrayList.contains take only one parametr. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.contains.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .NET 1.1 because Generics aren't available, you could do something like this:

```
bool contains = false;
for (int i = 0; i < myArrayList.Count && !contains; i++)
{
    contains = ((string)myArrayList[i]).ToUpper() == "APPLE";
}
if (contains)
{
    statusLabel.Text = "ArrayList contains apple";
}
```

Otherwise, using `List<string>` instead of ArrayList, then `myArrayList.Contains("apple", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` will work.

If you have .NET 2 + Generics available to you; then there really is no good reason to be using the `ArrayList` anymore.

Comment: You should use the .ToUpper() method because of this [CA1308: Normalize strings to uppercase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386042.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You should use `List<string>` instead of `ArrayList`.
Your code will then work as-is.

Comment: Almost down-voted, but realised that I need to add `using System.Linq;` to get this working. Just sayin'... for future googlers.

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.List is case sensitive. So this answer is wrong as it is.

Comment: @Elmue: I mean the `Contains()` call with a comparer at the end of the question.

Comment: OK. So you should write one sentence more. Your answer is too short.

Answer (score 0):

personally I'd prefer to use this function rather than lowering the whole string..

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows case insensitive checks
    /// </summary>
    public static bool Contains(this string source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp)
    {
        return source.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
    }
}
```

EDIT: usage of the code..

```
ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
            myArrayList.Add("Apple");
            myArrayList.Add("Banana");

foreach(var item in myArrayList)
{
    if(StringExtensions.Contains(statusLabel.Text, item.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
       //true.. do whatever you want in here...
       statusLabel.Text = "ArrayList contains " + item.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is that a response to my answer? This code only compares strings, it doesn't explain how to look in a collection in a case-insensitive way.

Comment: nope its not. I usually use this function to do case-insensitive checks for strings. instead of using regex or the useless String.Contain() function. so all he needs to replace the Contain function with this one and everything will work flawlessly...

Comment: Your code is an extension method on `string`. There are three problems with this. 1) If OP is using .NET 1.1; this is not possible. 2) An array list is not strongly typed, so it's an `object`. Since you're extending string, not object, the extension method will be unavailable. 3) It checks `IndexOf`, so "apple" will match if one of the items contains "applebees" even though the strings aren't the same. We are trying to see if a *collection* contains a string, not a string inside another string.